# grep part of text from ps output with regex

Tags: regex, shell, grep, ps

From `ps -ef` command output `-Dorg.xxx.yyy=/home/user/aaa/server.log`.

I'd like to extract the file path `/home/user/aaa/server.log` (can be any name.file).

Now, I'm using command:

```
ps -ef | grep -Po '(?<=-Dorg.xxx.yyy=)[^\s]*'
```

It will display two matched results:

```
/home/user/aaa/server.log
)[^\s]*
```

It looks like it counts the command as well for the 2nd matched result. How can I remove it? Or is there other suggestions? (I can not use `-m1`).

Comment: I don't have that behavior, with version of grep are you using? `grep --version`

Comment: it's grep (GNU grep) 2.18

Comment: I think it's correct behaviour because ps -ef it's listed in its result as well

Comment: Try `org\.xxx\.yyy=\K[^\s]*`.

Comment: yes, it works , thank you stribizhev

Comment: @user1684651 sure, misunderstood, sry

Comment: @user1684651: Posted as an answer since it worked for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need the file name, use `\K` operator:

```
org\.xxx\.yyy=\K[^\s]*

ps -ef | grep -Po 'org\.xxx\.yyy=\K[^\s]*'
```

It will match the whole string, but will only print the file name matched with `[^\s]*`.

From [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html):

> There is a special form of this construct, called \K (available since
>   Perl 5.10.0), which causes the regex engine to "keep" everything it
>   had matched prior to the \K and not include it in $& . This
>   effectively provides variable-length look-behind.

Comment: If you found my answer helpful, please also consider upvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Use that:

```
grep -Po '(?<=-[D]org.xxx.yyy=)[^\s]*'
```

Just put one of the characters in square brackets (`[D]`). The meaning of the regex hasn't changed and the pattern doesn't match itself anymore.